# Zend_Form setMultiFile()

Tags: zend-framework

i got a question related to the setMultiFile method of zend_form.

I already got a form like this:

```
$foto->setLabel('Foto:');
      $foto->addValidator('IsImage', true);
      $foto->addValidator('Count', true, 12);
      $foto->addValidator('Extension', true, 'gif,png,jpg');
      $foto->setDestination(PUBLIC_PATH.'/upload/img/');
      $foto->addFilter('Rename', array(
             'target' => PUBLIC_PATH.'/upload/img/', 
             'overwrite' => true
      ));
      $foto->setMultiFile(12);
      $foto->addDecorators(array(
           array('Description',array('tag'=>'','escape'=>false))
      ));
```

And it's everything working...but now i need to iterate each element to set a description and decorators...any suggestions ? Thanks to everyone that will reply to this, i'm drivin crazy with that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What elements are you talking about? If this is about form elements, then you can use something like this:

```
$form->setElementsDecorators(array('ViewHelper', 'Label'));
```

Comment: I mean each element created by setMultiFile() method...i need to show to the user a preview of the current image near each input file...and i need to iterate them 1 by 1 bcuz i want to resize each images using phpThumb...